External Secrets unable to read plain text
Hi I have an external Secrets created that I want to read the secrets from SSM Parameter.
However this secrets are stored as string rather than JSON format.
I'm getting this error:

unable to unmarshal secret /secret/path/to/MY_SECRET: invalid character 'd' looking for beginning of value

The value of MY_SECRET is dummy. I expected this to happen because the External Secret is expecting a json format.
But IDK how write in the yaml to allow ES to take the string rather than expecting a dictionary.
apiVersion: external-secrets.io/v1beta1
kind: ExternalSecret
metadata:
  name: my-test-es
  namespace: my-namespace
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: external-secrets
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: external-secrets
spec:
  refreshInterval: 10m
  secretStoreRef:
    name: my-test-cluster-secret-store
    kind: ClusterSecretStore
  target:
    name: my-test-secret-test-es
  dataFrom:
    - extract:
        key: /secret/path/to/MY_SECRET

I know that it is expecting a json format as I have tested it with an example and it works fine.
Perhaps, I should convert it as json first? How can I do that if that is an option? Thanks!

Th trick is to use another name for Parameter Store key, for example :
  dataFrom:
    - extract:
        key: /secret/path/to/MY_SECRET_PARAM_NAME

and it's value would be a JSON like :
{"MY_SECRET":"dummy"}

in your EKS pods (I suppose it's EKS but it's doesn't make difference) this would be transalated as a variable enviornement like MY_SECRET=dummy

Thanks for the respond! I don't quite understand with using another name because when you create the value in SSM, it automatically use the name we wrote

Sorry maybe I didn't explain this well, create a parameter with a name MY_SECRET_PARAM_NAME or whatever you want. this is the name you specify in the dataFrom section of the external secret. the content of this parameter is your secrets that will be in JSON : {"MY_SECRET":"dummy"}
